# Flutter - How to integrate React Native SDK in to existing Flutter Project?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, sdk

I have flutter project which was published on Google playstore. To add some functionality, I found in React Native SDK, I would like to integrate this react-native sdk into my existing flutter project.

How can i add that ?

Answer (score 0):

I searched Google and found these 2 solutions:

- https://kps250.medium.com/flutter-integration-with-react-native-e796fc42556f
- https://github.com/mattreid1/react-native-with-flutter

Seems like they cannot integrate React Native into Flutter for iOS, only Android works.

I used to want to integrate RN into Flutter with PDF functionalities - which only available for RN. But my boss doesn't agree, they told that is a worst decision. Therefore I have to use MethodChannel with Kotlin + Swift. I succeed anyway, but it was a hard work.